# WP Plugin CSS not being applied to page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, css

I am making a shortcode plugin that sends a variable to a JS script.
The CSS is not being applied to the page with the shortcode or any other page. Any idea to fix this, please? The CSS link does exist in the page source when I checked.

```
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts' );


        function register_scripts() {
        wp_register_script( 'NN', plugins_url( 'main.js', __FILE__ ),
            'jquery', 0.01, true );
        wp_register_style( 'namespace', plugins_url( 'main.css', __FILE__ ),
            'css', 0.03, true );
        }

        add_shortcode( 'Now', 'my_handle_shortcode' );


        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript' );


        function load_javascript() {        
        $NN=1;

        wp_localize_script( 'NN', 'NN', array( 'text' => $NN ) );

        function my_handle_shortcode() {

        return '
        <div id="inner">
        <span ></span>
        </div>
        ';
        wp_enqueue_script( 'NN' );
        wp_enqueue_style('namespace');  

        }

        } //end load js -->
```

Comment: Why is `my_handle_shortcode()` *inside* `load_javascript()`?

Comment: Are you trying to load css to a specific page? Why not just enqueue it for that page using a conditional?